# Proof Verification: Spivak's Calculus, Chapter 1, Problem 8

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

This is a proof for Spivak's Calculus 4th ed., Chapter 1, Problem 8.

> Prove that for every number $a$, one and only one of the
>   following holds:
>
> (i) $a = 0$,
>
> (ii) $a$ is in the collection $P$ (all the positive numbers),
>
> (iii) $—a$ is in the collection $P$.
>
> (The Trichotomy Law)

Here are the properties that I was allowed to use

> $(PI)$ (Associative law for addition) $a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c$
>
> $(P2)$ (Existence of an additive identity) $a+0=0+a=a$
>
> $(P3)$ (Existence of additive inverses) $a+(-a)=(-a)+a=0$
>
> $(P4)$ (Commutative law for addition) $a+b=b+a$
>
> $(P5)$ (Associative law for multiplication) $a\cdot(b\cdot c)=(a\cdot b)\cdot c$
>
> $(P6)$ (Existence of a multiplicative identity) $a\cdot 1=1\cdot a=a, 1\neq0$
>
> $(P7)$ (Existence of multiplicative inverses) $a\cdot a^{-1}=a^{-1}\cdot a = 1$, for $a\neq0$
>
> $(P8)$ (Commutative law for multiplication) $a\cdot b = b\cdot a$
>
> $(P9)$ (Distributive law) $a(b+c)= ab+ac$
>
> $(P'10)$ For any numbers $a$ and $b$, one and only one holds:
>
> (i) $a=b$
>
> (ii) $a>b$
>
> (iii) $a<b$
>
> $(P'11)$ For any numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$, if $a<b$ and $b<c$, then $a<c$.
>
> $(P'12)$ For any numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$, if $a<b$, then $a+c<b+c$.
>
> $(P'13)$ For any numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$, if $a<b$ and $c>0$, then $ac<bc$.

And here is my proof:

If, for two numbers $a$ and $b$, $a=b$, it is easy to prove that $b-a=0$.

If, $a<b$, it is easy to prove that $0<b-a$.

If, $a>b$, it is easy to prove that $0<-(b-a)$.

$\therefore$ As any real number can be expressed as the sum of two other real numbers, I can let $x=b-a$ such that either $x=0$ or $x>0$ or $-x>0$.

My worry isn't proving the "this is easy to prove" parts as I'm fine with those. However, I am concerned if I can assume that I can let any number $x=b-a$.

Does this proof make sense?

Comment: That looks overly complicated. You'd need that the real numbers are closed under addition as an axiom. Can't you just combine P'10 with P2?

Comment: Not everyone has spivak in front of them.  You should explain what Spivak means by The set of all Positive numbers.  He clearly doesn't mean all $n > 0$ (that make this just by P10 with $b=0$)  Do you know what he *does* mean?

Comment: Argh... nevermind.  But you can let $x = b-a$ because $b-a = b+(-a)$ and the reals are closed under addition.  But this is even *easier*.  Just let $b = 0$.

Comment: Oops... never mind it is *not* okay to say let $x= b-a$ because although $a,b$ are generic any numbers, $x$ is a specific not generc, not any old number.  To make you proof valid (if you still want to) you must also prove that for any old general $x$ you can find $a$ and $b$ so that $x = b-a$.  That's actually very easy to prove.  (Just let $b =x$ and $a =0$)  But no your proof is really round about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I am concerned if I can assume that I can let any number x=b−a"

Well, yes and no but mostly no.

You were asked to prove:  For any number, $symbol$, that something is true for $symbol$.

You proved: For any two numbers, $a,b$ something is true for $a-b$.  If we let $symbol = a-b$ then it is true for $symbol$.  So something is true for all numbers $symbol$ where $symbol$ may be written as a difference of two numbers.

But you have neither considered numbers that *can't* be written as a difference of two numbers, nor have you considered proving that any number $symbol$ *can* be written as a difference of two numbers.

If you do either of those the proof is complete.

Proving that any number $symbol$ is easy:  Pick any number $d$ at all (some numbers do exist so this is possible).  Let $a = symbol + d$ and $b = d$ then $a - d = symbol + d - d = symbol$ and .... ta-da.

But really your proof can be much easy:

P'(10) says that for any two numbers $a$ and $b$ that either $a < b; a=b;$  or $a < 0$.  Let $a$ be any number and $b$ be $0$.  Then either $a < 0$ or $a = 0$ or $a > 0$.

I assume that when you said it "was easy" to prove that if $a > b$ then $b-a < 0$ that it will be just as easy to prove if $a < 0$ that $-a > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly give a name ($x$) to the difference of two real numbers ($b$ and $a$).  That follows from (P3), which essentially says that the real numbers are closed under subtraction.

But I'm a bit confused by your use of $b$ in the first place.  The statement you are asked to prove is:

> For all real numbers $a$, either $a \in P$, $-a \in P$, or $a=0$.

There's no reference to a second number $b$, but your proof creates one and proves statements about $b-a$.

However, you can use a *specific* number $b$ and invoke (P'10) to prove the statements required.

Comment: So if I let b=0 would that make sense?

Comment: "So if I let b=0 would that make sense?" That'd make *perfect* sense.  Just have to prove that if $a < 0$ then $-a > 0$.  Which is easy.